# Seriousness values on OpenFDA

Tags: data.gov, openfda

In looking at [OpenFDA](http://open.fda.gov/), I'd like to know the range of values for results.seriousnessother, results.seriousnesshospitalization, results.serious, and results.primarysource.qualification, as well as what they mean.

Comment: I think you need to add more context to this question so we can help to answer it.

Comment: David, what data are you talking about?

Comment: I've flagged this for Sean Herron, who works on the OpenFDA team.

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at our API documentation (http://open.fda.gov/drug/event/reference/), you'll see a complete reference for every field we return and the range of possible values. We follow the E2b specification for adverse drug reporting (http://www.fda.gov/downloads/Drugs/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/Surveillance/AdverseDrugEffects/UCM350390.pdf).

For the specific examples you provided, here's what our documentation reads:

**seriousnesshospitalization**

> This value is 1 if the adverse event resulted in a hospitalization,
>   and absent otherwise.

**serious:**

> 1 = The adverse event resulted in death, a life threatening condition,
>   hospitalization, disability, congenital anomali, or other serious
>   condition.
>
> 2 = The adverse event did not result in any of the above.

**primarysource.qualification:**

> An encoded value for the category of individual submitting the report.
>
> 1 = Physician
>
> 2 = Pharmacist
>
> 3 = Other Health Professional
>
> 4 = Lawyer
>
> 5 = Consumer or non-health professional

Answer (score 2):

If you use our search tool you can find a graph (last one of 5) that tabulates the  results.primarysource.qualification into a bar graph for your search query. http://openfda.socialhealthinsights.com/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out http://www.fda.gov/downloads/Drugs/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/Surveillance/AdverseDrugEffects/UCM350390.pdf for more information on the data in these reports.