# openFDA adverse reaction Serious vs Expedited?

Tags: openfda

what is the difference between `serious` and `fulfillexpeditecriteria` ?

`fulfillexpeditecriteria` is not in the [docs](https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/).

Comment: Documentation about fulfillexpeditedcriteria will be added to open.fda.gov soon. See https://github.com/FDA/open.fda.gov/issues/66

Answer (score 1):

- For `serious` values mappings, see this similar SE question: [Seriousness values on OpenFDA](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2177/seriousness-values-on-openfda). The short answer is (quoting [Sean Herron](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/2987/sean-herron)):

  > 1 = The adverse event resulted in death, a life threatening condition, hospitalization, disability, congenital anomali, or other serious condition.
  >
  > 2 = The adverse event did not result in any of the above.
- For `fulfillexpeditecriteria` and other variables you may come across, I suggest referencing the PDF both Sean and I mentioned in the linked SE question: http://www.fda.gov/downloads/Drugs/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/Surveillance/AdverseDrugEffects/UCM350390.pdf . That document is not specific to OpenFDA but instead the source system upstream from the API OpenFDA exposes. The short answer is (quoting the PDF):

  > Value is 1 (1=yes) for identified expedited reports (15-day); 2 for all others.

**EDIT**: You can see more information on the fields at http://www.fda.gov/downloads/Drugs/DevelopmentApprovalProcess/FormsSubmissionRequirements/ElectronicSubmissions/UCM149932.pdf as well. For example, the following for `fulfillexpeditedcriteria`:

> Does this case fulfill the local criteria for an expedited report?

*Be sure to remember that different countries might have different standards*